# Linux programming: which device a file is in

Tags: c, linux, file, device

I would like to know which entry under /dev a file is in. For example, if /dev/sdc1 is mounted under /media/disk, and I ask for /media/disk/foo.txt, I would like to get /dev/sdc as response.

Using *stat* system call on that file I will get its partition major and minor numbers (8 and 33, for sdc1). Now I need to get the "root" device (sdc) or its major/minor from that. Is there any **syscall or library function** I could use to link a partition to its main device? Or even better, to get that device directly from the file?

```
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 8, 32 2011-04-01 20:00 /dev/sdc
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 8, 33 2011-04-01 20:00 /dev/sdc1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

The quick and dirty version:  `df $file | awk 'NR == 2 {print $1}'`.

Programmatically... well, there's a reason I started with the quick and dirty version.  There's no portable way to programmatically get the list of mounted filesystems.  (`getmntent()` gets `fstab` entries, which is not the same thing.)  Moreover, you can't even parse the output of `mount(8)` reliably; on different Unixes, the mountpoint may be the first or the last item.  The most portable way to do this ends up being... parsing `df` output  (And even that is iffy, as you noticed with the partition number.).  So you're right back to the quick and dirty shell solution anyway, unless you want to traverse `/dev` and look for block devices with matching `major(st_rdev)` (`major()` being from `sys/types.h`).

If you restrict this to Linux, you can use `/proc/mounts` to get the list of mounted filesystems.  Other specific Unixes can similarly be optimized:  for example, on OS X and I think FreeBSD, you can use `sysctl()` on the `vfs` tree to get mountpoints.  At worst you can find and use the appropriate header file to decipher whatever the mount table file is (and yes, even that varies:  on Solaris it's `/etc/mnttab`, on many other systems it's `/etc/mtab`, some systems put it in `/var/run` instead of `/etc`, and on many Linuxes it's either nonexistent or a symlink to `/proc/mounts`).  And its format is different on pretty much every Unix-like OS.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to achive this using only system/library calls. Also, your suggestion is giving me the partition number ;-)

Comment: @Grieih: +1 to this because you never specified you wanted this in C-code. P.S. adding `-F'[0-9]'` will remove the partition number

Comment: @Greih: see update. I went with that for a reason, unfortunately.

Comment: @geek: ok my bad. I added the C tag and bolded that statement so it doesn't get overlooked

Comment: @geekosaur: I see. I wanted this function to be inside a C program, and although I could parse /proc or /dev entries from there, I'd like to avoid doing it. Maybe the question was too general, so I'll stick with Linux. Removed 'unix' from question.

Comment: If you restrict it to Linux, you can use `/proc/mounts` to get and iterate over the mountpoints.  Updating response.

Comment: @Grieih, although `system()` should be avoided as a general rule, things like this are what it was made for.  As it allows for more portability in this case, I wouldn't feel bad at all about using it.

Comment: Indeed; I got to see the full horror of this when writing a filesystem monitor that needed to work on Linux versions spanning 2.2 to 2.6 kernels, several Solaris versions, AIX 4.3, and Tru64. In the end, I made sure every system I needed to worry about had GNU `df` installed (actually, they did already) and parsed its output.

Comment: -1: This doesn't answer the question at all - that is, "what is the root device of a partition". This answer only gives you the partition device.

Comment: @camh: that's even less possible to automate; it adds "how does the driver allocate minor numbers?" to the equation — not to mention "so what do you do if it's LVM/GVinum/RAID/etc.?" Have fun storming *that* castle. I got as close as it's possible to get in practice; I'm sorry if this offends your sensibilities.

Comment: @geekosaur: I'm not offended at all. I'm just explaining why I downvoted. I understood that was polite.

Answer (score 3):

The information you want exists in sysfs which exposes the linux device tree. This models the relationships between the devices on the system and since you are trying to determine a parent disk device from a partition, this is the place to look. I don't know if there are any hard and fast rules you can rely on to stop your code breaking with future versions of the kernel, but the kernel developers do try to maintain sysfs as a stable interface.

If you look at `/sys/dev/block/<major>:<minor>`, you'll see it is a symlink with the tail components being `block/<disk-device-name>/<partition-device-name>`. If you were to perform a `readlink(2)` system call on that, you could parse the link destination to get the disk device name. In shell (since it's easier to express this way, but doing it in C will be pretty easy):

```
$ echo $(basename $(dirname $(readlink /sys/dev/block/8:33)))
sdc
```

Alternatively, you could take advantage of the nesting of partition directories in the disk directories (again in shell, but from C, its an `open(2)`, `read(2)`, and `close(2)`):

```
$ cat /sys/dev/block/8:33/../dev
8:32
```

That assumes your starting major:minor is actually for a partition, not some other sort of non-nested device.

Answer (score 2):

What you looking for is impossible - there is no 1:1 connection between a block device file and the partition it is describing.

Consider:

1. You can create multiple block device files with different names (but the same major and minor numbers) and they are indistinguishable (N:1)
2. You can use a block device file as an argument to mount to mount a partition and then delete the block device file leaving the partition mounted. (0:1)

So there is no way to do what you want except in a few specific and narrow cases.

Answer (score 1):

Major number will tell you which device it is: 3 - IDE on 1st controller, 22 - IDE on 2nd controller and 8 for SCSI.

Minor number will tell you partition number and - for IDE devices - if it's primary or secondary drive. This calculation is different for IDE and SCSI.

For IDE it is: x*64 + p, x is drive number on the controller (0 or 1) and p is partition

For SCSI it is: y*16 + p, where y is drive number and p is partition

Answer (score 0):

Not a syscall, but:

`df -h /path/to/my/file`

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128471/determine-what-device-a-directory-is-located-on

So you could look at df's source code and see what it does.

*I realize this post is old, but this question was the 2nd result in my search and no one has mentioned `df -h`*